# Изменить ширину таблиц в админке Django

Tags: django

В админке Django, в части permissions я не могу расширить колонки прав пользователя. Полные названия прав не помещаются, и я могу только догадываться, что именно я выбираю:

[image: permissions]

Я пытался указать ширину через `classes`, но это не помогло:

```
 ...
(_('Permissions'), {
    'classes': ('wide',),
    'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
               'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
```

Мне бы хотелось растянуть колонки на всю ширину страницы или добавит возможность вручную растягивать колонки. Подскажите, что именно нужно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из возможных вариантов решения проблемы.
В директории приложения создаёте следующую структуру каталогов:

```
templates
    admin
        <имя модели>
            <имя_файла.html>
```

**имя_файла.html**

```
{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}
{% load i18n admin_urls %}

{% block extrastyle %}
  {{ block.super }}
  <style>
    .selector {
      width: 1800px;
      float: left;
    }

    .selector select {
      width: 850px;
      height: 17.2em;
    }

    .selector-available, .selector-chosen {
      float: left;
      width: 850px;
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
  </style>
{% endblock %}
```

**admin.py**

в модели переопределяете атрибут `change_form_template`:

```
change_form_template = <путь до имя_файла.html>
```